# git from a C# application

Tags: c#, git, open-source

Currently writing a C# application it should do backups using GIT in the background.
I'm looking for projects or examples to do that without showing any GUI or bash shell..

When searching cross by GitSharp - https://github.com/henon/GitSharp.
It seems close to what I've looked for yet it isn't active.. (see the pull req')

Would like to get recommendations for open source projects or source code to do that.

Comment: GitSharp works great, it should suffice for basic operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[libgit2sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) are C# bindings for `libgit2`, which the official GitHub for Windows client uses. They should be decent.

Comment: Thanks - will check it as well.

Comment: After checking the libgit2sharp - it has several issues mainly a none existence push support..

Answer (score 1):

Try [ngit](https://github.com/mono/ngit), it have better codebase but no decent docs